# make: extract elements from dependency

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a target of the form `target: DEP1 DEP2` where `DEP1` and `DEP2` are a list of items. Say `DEP1 = A B C`, `DEP2 = D E F`. I need to extract some elements from `DEP2`, i.e.

```
target: $(DEP1) $(DEP2)
    # echo E from DEP2 without explicitly using $(DEP2)
```

Is there a way I Can do this? I've seen the usage of `$(word 2, $^)` to extract the second *dependency* but I'm unsure as to how to extract an element *from* a dependency.

Thanks.

EDIT: fixed a syntax mistake and attempted to clarify

Comment: Put the list into a `DEP2` variable (it's not clear if you are already doing that) and then `$(word 2, $(DEP2))`?

Comment: Do you mean `target: DEP1 DEP2` or `target: $(DEP1) $(DEP2)`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `target: $(DEP1) $(DEP2)`. And I'm hoping to do so in the target without expliciting referencing `DEP2` in the target body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're asking.  Make will expand all variables in the prerequisites list as the makefile is read in, so before make even starts to parse the line any indication of what values might have been contained in which variable is long gone.

That is there's absolutely no way to tell the difference between ANY of the following constructions simply by looking at the list of prerequisites:

```
DEP1 = A B C
DEP2 = D E F
target: $(DEP1) $(DEP2)

DEP1 = A
DEP2 = B C D E F
target: $(DEP1) $(DEP2)

target: A B C D E F
```

all exactly identical in terms of the contents of automatic variables such as `$^` etc.